# How to reduce the loglevel of deadlock logs from SqlExceptionHelper?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm getting a lot of deadlock error messages in my logs, the reason for the deadlock itself is acceptable behavior, and the error messages are "polluting" the logs. The error is "Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction"

We're acquiring the lock at the time of reading from a table, and it's used in a transaction that does "upsert", something like;

```
-> start transaction with @Transactional on method
-> acquire the lock, and fetch entities with @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) annotation on the repository
-> call repository.save for entities that need to be updated, and entities that need to be inserted
-> persist another entity through another repository (history)
-> end transaction
```

I want to set the log level for just the message "Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction" to debug or trace. Is this possible?

Comment: Not unless you modify the code.

Comment: How would I do that? I don't see any stacktrace in the logs, is there an exception I can catch from save or read method?

Comment: For those who wonder why anybody would want to do this, I have the same problem. I use SQL table locking for synchronizing nodes in a cluster, and failing to acquire a lock with NOWAIT (perfectly acceptable) results in an ERROR in the logs (not acceptable).